# how to verify email address for signup with email in android app

Tags: android, mysql, email, android-intent, android-volley

In my android application registration I am planning to ask users email address, so i can use the same for if they forgot their application password.So I need to verify the given email address and I found that there is no provision to confirm the existence of email address.But I think if we can send a OTP or verification link to that email then that help me to verify the email id.How can I do that??If anyone know that please help me.I need to send the OTP or verification link to email and ask the users to enter the OTP and then verify the same.

Comment: Post the code that you tried to achieve your requirement after your analysis.

Comment: i don't have any idea how to do that.

Comment: i just wanna to verify my user's email address

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to have a server module to do that.
Create a web service / REST API to collect an email from your client app and send a verification code using some EMAIL. (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server)

Or you can use some 3rd party services which does the similar things for you

**Email Verification:**

https://kickbox.io/

http://quickemailverification.com/

**Phone Verification:**

https://fabric.io/kits/android/digits - Free

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy/authy-phone-verification-api - Metered

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party email verification service and validate the email address on-demand.

Some providers like MailBoxValidator provides free tier with 300 queries per month. It is a good starting point for app developers.

**Email Validation API**

http://mailboxvalidator.com

http://verify-email.org

http://kickbox.io

http://neverbounce.com

http://briteverify.com